# Per-user installation does not work with turned on UAC (default level) on Windows 7

Tags: wix, windows-installer, uac

I created a per-user installation MSI package.

According to tutorials, if installation does not write files outside of %USERPROFILE% and does not change the registry outside of HKCU, then such installation could be installed by a plain user without administrator rights.

But on my computers with turned on [UAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Account_Control) (default level), the following message appears and the system asks for the administrator's login and password:

> Do you want to allow the following program from an unknown publisher to make changes to this computer

Does my installation make some not-permitted changes? Or it is normal behavior of Windows 7 and a plain user cannot install per-user applications at all?

Comment: Something is definitely writing outside USERPROFILE therefore the UAC message. Set InstallScope="perUser" in Package then build, i think you should get warnings/errors if you have anything that are against perUser scope. If you don't get anything then you should consider posting some of your code.

Comment: I forget to add InstallScope. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to setting InstallScope="perUser" you must also set InstallPrivileges="limited" so you will have something like this:

```
<Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perUser" InstallPrivileges="limited"/>
```

Comment: Correct but you don't have to set it explicitly since the InstallScope will do that for you, from the doc:
perUser
Set this value to declare that the package is a per-user installation and does not require elevated privileges to install. Sets the package's InstallPrivileges attribute to "limited."

Answer (score 0):

The comment about unknown publisher is not administrator-related. It just means that the MSI file isn't signed.

You should post some of your WiX `Package` stuff in case you have just got InstallPrivileges set to `Elevated` or `InstallScope` as permachine. These can cause that elevation prompt.

Note that you don't get an elevation prompt, because Windows has detected that your setup might change restricted parts of the system, because it doesn't know yet! It's a setting in your WiX source. If the setup didn't get an elevation prompt and proceeded that's when you'd find out if you were violating security, and the setup would fail.